# Django "Latest" filter with multiple values

Tags: django

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Date            Value
Oct. 23, 2018   -400
Oct. 23, 2018   -1100
Oct. 23, 2018   -200
Oct. 22, 2018   -400
Oct. 22, 2018   -1100
Oct. 21, 2018   -400
```

I would like to return the latest value for the date, but with multiple results.

filter().latest() only returns one object. I'd need three in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to post the model for your table? It would help with determining a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can give a try:

`filter('some_filter_conditions').order_by('-date')[:3]`

Comment: Sure but the amount of records is not fixed every day

Comment: @justinlevol Then in can be converted into function or model method that accepts amount of records as parameter, eg `lambda records_number: Object.order_by('-date')[:records_number]`